# Does a Hammerdin profit from the elemental damage of Tiamats shield?

Tags: diablo-ii, diablo-ii-resurrected

Will the elmemental damage of [Tiamat's Rebuke](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Tiamat%27s_Rebuke) be added to the Paladin attack [Blessed Hammer](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Blessed_Hammer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**.

All the "Adds X to Elemental Damage" work only for melee attacks.

Blessed Hammer is a spell, and spells generally benefit from "+ % Elemental Damage" or "- % To Enemy Elemental Resistance", but Blessed Hammer is pretty unique and it deals not elemental, but [Magic damage](https://diablo-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Magic). AFAIK, there are no items with bonuses to it. So the only way to boost it is from "+ X to Skills" bonuses and from Paladin's [Concentration](https://diablo-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Concentration_(Diablo_II)) aura.

Comment: Is [Smite](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Smite) also a spell or is it a melee attack? How to know, if a skill is a spell?

Comment: @ceving Smite is a melee attack, but once again - it's special because it's a shield strike and not a weapon strike. So not all bonuses work for it, see this post with nice description of what works for Smite https://diablo2.io/post17368.html?sid=8ffac9181cd6a218843df6785ab41145#p17368